# having trouble with a git sparse checkout (folder)

Tags: bash, git, sparse-checkout

here is my git server tree:

```
----a/
    |--b/
    |--c/
    |--d/
       |--e/
          |--f/
             |--g.txt
          |--h.readme
```

here is my git version tree

```
---------------->master
    |---->myBranch [files are up to date here]
```

here is my jenkins server tree

```
-----A/
     |--B/
     |--C/
```

I am trying to checkout the content of repository "e" in repository "B"
I just need the last version of the current branch i'm working on, and I don't want to commit, just to get some up-to-date read-only scripts to run, so `depth 1` is okay I guess.

Anyway, The problem I'm facing is that I'm able to to a sparse checkout with

```
#############################
#####    1/ configuring local folder
#############################
git init
git config core.sparseCheckout true
#an empty repository with the remote is created:
git remote add -f origin ssh://guillaumedg@domain.com:port/myProjects/thisProject.git
#add repository "e" to be checked out:
echo e/*> .git/info/sparse-checkout
#############################
#####    2/ fetching/updating files
#############################
git fetch 
git checkout myBranch
```

I know I'm close, but what I get is this:

```
-----A/
     |--B/
     |  |----a/
     |       |--d/
     |          |--e/
     |             |--f/
     |                |--g.txt
     |             |--h.readme
     |--C/
```

not this **(which is what I want)**

```
-----A/
     |--B/
     |  |--f/
     |     |--g.txt
     |  |--h.readme
     |--C/
```

any hints?

by the way I tried different ways of using "depth 1" for "step 2" with no success:

```
git fetch --depth 1 $(url) $(branch)
git checkout $(branch)
```

> --> error: pathspec 'myBranch' did not match any file(s) known to git.

```
git fetch --depth 1 $(url) $(branch)
git checkout
```

> --> fatal: You are on a branch yet to be born

```
git fetch --depth 1 $(url) $(branch)
git checkout -b $(branch)
```

> fatal: A branch named 'myBranch' already exists.

```
git fetch
git checkout $(branch)
```

> --> works as describe above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git doesn't store directories, only files.  So, given your drawing here:

> ```
> ----a/
>     |--b/
>     |--c/
>     |--d/
>        |--e/
>           |--f/
>              |--g.txt
>           |--h.readme
> ```

the repository has some commits that have files named:

```
a/d/e/f/g.txt
```

and:

```
a/d/e/h.readme
```

You can direct your Git to check out these specific files, using either command line options or the sparse checkout option you're attempting to use.  Their names will still be `a/d/e/f/g.txt` and `a/d/e/h.readme`.

Your computer probably requires that these names be created by making a directory (or folders) named `a`, then making one named `d` in `a`, and so on.  Git will do that.  You cannot make Git use any other name for these files if you're going to use `git checkout` to extract them.<sup>1</sup>

So, that leaves you with the option of *not* using `git checkout` to get these files.  You could get the commit (as you are doing already), then use `git show` on individual path names, for instance.  The standard output of `git show` will show the file's contents; you can redirect this to a file name of your choice.

Since you don't want the whole repository, consider using `git archive` to turn *one* commit into an archive.  Since you don't want the whole commit either, consider adding to this `git archive` command the name(s) of the file(s) that you want archived.<sup>2</sup>  You may then have an un-archiver that can *skip* the `a/d/` part of the path names of each archived file.  For instance, GNU tar has `--strip-components`.

---

<sup>1</sup>I think it would be nice to be able to remap stored file names to in-file-system names, for many reasons, including the case-folding issues and cheeky Linux programmers creating files named `CON` and `LPT`. :-)  But Git can't, at least not today.

<sup>2</sup>This isn't *required*, and if you're downloading this kind of `git archive` from a hosting server such as GitHub, you may not be able to do that.  But if you *can* do that, you'll save some amount of space and transfer time.  Given your `ssh://user@host` URL, you can probably run `ssh user@host "cd path/to/repo; git archive ..."` and pipe the result to a local `tar -xf -`, for instance.